# SQL - add column to select and fiil it

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

There is a table:
id column_1 column_2 ...
and there is an array of some ids 
Help me to create such a select so that there will be new column zzz with 1 if id is in ids or with 0 if id is not in ids.
id ... zzz 
123 ... 0
4121 ... 0
22... 1 <= this id (22) is in array [12,22,456,56]
562... 0
23523... 0

Comment: _"Help me to create "_ why don't you show us what you have tried first?

Comment: select id, column_1, column_2, zzz from mytable :)

Comment: And it doesn't work? Secondly (Which I should properly have mentioned in my first comment, your question is rather confusing, are you trying to select data or insert/create data?

Comment: really a terrible question.. help us to create a decent answer by properly explaining yourself and showing some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, column_1, column_2,
case when id in (12,22,456,56) then 1 else 0 end as zzz
from tablename
```

The `IN` clause in the case statement can be replaced with a table name having those id's like:

```
select id, column_1, column_2,
case when id in (select distinct id from table2) then 1 else 0 end as zzz
from tablename
```